# return the entire tag using xml::Twig

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

How can I return the entire xml tag using xml::twig and save it to array:

for example :

```
my @array=();
my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
twig_handlers => {
'data'=> sub {push @array, $_->xml_string;}

});
```

This code return all the nested tags but without the tag itself and its properties is there an option to return the entire tag using xml::twig and save it to varaible  ?

Comment: Can you please provide a working example with some input?

Comment: Nevermind. I made some myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use XML::Twigs method `sprint` instead of `xml_string`. The [docs](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig/Twig.pm) say that:

> xml_string @optional_options
>
> ```
> Equivalent to $elt->sprint( 1), returns the string for the entire element, excluding the element's tags (but nested element tags are present)
> ```

A search for that `sprint` function yields:

> sprint
>
> ```
> Return the text of the whole document associated with the twig. To be used only AFTER the parse.
> ```

Thus, you can do the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Twig;

my @array=();
my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
twig_handlers => {
  'data'=> sub {push @array, $_->sprint;}
});

$twig->parse(qq~
  <xml>
        <data id="foo">
      <deep>
            <deeper>the deepest</deeper>
      </deep>
    </data>
  </xml>
~);

print Dumper \@array;
```

Which prints:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '<data id="foo"><deep><deeper>the deepest</deeper></deep></data>'
        ];
```